# Java IntStream iterate vs generate when to use what?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

It seems `IntStream.iterate` is just a lightweight ordered version for `IntStream.generate`.
Is it true? If not, what is the core difference?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Note how their signatures are different:

- `generate` takes a `IntSupplier`, which means that you are supposed to generate ints without being given anything. Example usages include creating a constant stream of the same integer, creating a stream of random integers. Notice how each element in the stream do not depend on the previous element.
- `iterate` takes a `seed` and a `IntUnaryOperator`, which means that you are supposed to generate each element *based on the previous element*. This is useful for creating a inductively defined sequence, for example. In this case, each element is supposed to *depend on the previous one*.

Comment: So use case of iterate - when need to save state - this is the core difference. Generate need to store state somewhere else. And Iterate is ordered, while generate is unordered which is viable for parralelism

Answer (score 8):

1. `IntStream.iterate` returns an *ordered `IntStream`* on the other hand `IntStream.generate` returns an *unordered `IntStream`* which can help in speeding up parallel stream pipelines.
2. `IntStream.generate` are preferred to generate random or constant values as specified in the Javadoc, I would guess most likely for the characteristics of the stream returned.

Answer (score 5):

Aside from order, also the usage is a bit different. Let's look at the method signatures:

- `iterate(int seed, IntUnaryOperator f)`
- `generate(IntSupplier s)`

Iterate has explicitly given starting value as parameter and unary operator which is used to generate next value from previous. Here operator can easily be immutable without internal state and can be reused in multiple places in parallel without any issue.

Generate uses supplier. Those can either provide constant or random numbers or need to have internal state to provide series like (1, 2, 3, ...).